# Optimal XDebug settings

Tags: debugging, local, xdebug

I am currently trying to locally debug a Magento installation using a Windows 8.1 machine, XAMPP, XDebug and Sublime Text 3 XDebug client. It currently runs so slow, it is pretty much unusable while debugging (40 to 90 second page loads - almost all of that is the initial page request, not external file requests). Here are the settings I am using. Is there a better way?

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "xdebug_profile.%R::%u"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```